# Where can I find wind maps for the Mediterranean/Middle East?

Tags: data, maps

I do debris modeling, sim, and analysis for missile interceptions. I have been looking for hours and I can't seem to find the information I'm looking for. So my question is...

Where can I find historical wind speed data for multiple altitude (basically as high up as you can get data) in the Mediterranean/Middle East? And is there even a place you can get that?

Comment: You may want to consider posting your question to the [opendata.se] (Beta) Stack Exchange.